# Are there other 'casual outfits' available for Shepard?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Mass Effect 2 introduced the idea of additional, customizable 'casual' attire that Shepard could wear aboard the Normandy, as well as during visits to the Citadel and other non-combat locations.

And like any good RPG, playing dress-up is first and foremost in my mind.

ME2 didn't have any other options in the base game aside from the 4 that Shepard started with.

**Other than the N7 Hoodie**, available as part of a Collectors Edition, are there any other casual attire options obtainable within ME3, **beyond the default five**?

Comment: gee, thanks for not making that clear when you *first* asked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way outside of DLC/Collectors Edition or altering game files to expand the availiable 'casual' attire options.

Answer (score 7):

If you use a save editor and change the right Boolean values to "true", you can get a total of 10 outfits.

- **22590** enables the tracksuit from the Collector's Edition
- **21752** enables four other casual outfits: injured, underwear, clothes worn during first Reaper attack on Earth, and "casual scientist outfit from *ME2*"

It even works on the Xbox 360 version.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the links below are SFW, as they are VERY causal outfits.
Both require editing the coalesced.bin file to activate and are definitely not available as a normal in game feature.

**FemShep**

Bra and panties hack... looks like [Udina's office](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0SeY.jpg)

Nice bit of design (lace) work on the bra, too bad they didn't spend more time on (especially) her arms.  A really unrealistic body type, especially for a female soldier.  Conveys an eating disorder, not strength.

**MaleShep**

The male Shepard gets a pair of black boxers and a muscle bound physique that would make statues of Greek gods jealous.  This collage shows him [wandering around level 1](http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/058/4/b/mass_effect_3_underwear_by_tippingwater-d4r58hr.png), getting felt up by the Admiral and generally looking odd without a uniform.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for male Shepards?

Comment: @Shinrai I found this, but I don't know if it's from actual in game or a pic edit ...

Comment: Causal outfits... hehe...